# Is it true $GS(TA)=T GS(A)$ where GS denotes the Gram Schmidt process and $T \in O(n,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ denote an $n \times n$ matrix.Suppose $GS:GL(n,\mathbb R) \to O(n,\mathbb R)$ denotes the Gram Schmidt orthogonalization process.Is it true that

> GS(TA)= TGS(A) where $T$ is an orthogonal matrix?

I think the claim is true but unable to write a proper proof.Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect so - the GS process works such that the first $k$ output vectors have the same span as the first $k$ input vectors, and form an orthonormal set. Applying an orthogonal transformation to both inputs and outputs simultaneously ought to preserve all of these relevant properties. You could also consider the algorithmic presentation of the GS process and note that the dot products involved will have the same values (because $T$ is orthogonal).

Comment: I suppose also that you can consider Gram-Schmidt as forming a QR factorisation $A=QR$, and that if $T$ is orthogonal, $TA=(TQ)R$ is also a QR factorisation. Not sure this constitutes a proof but basically captures why we might expect it to be true.

Comment: @πr8: yeah it seems that the claim should be true but via the first you've suggested it seems to me that writing the proof actually would be too messy.

Comment: It might be cleaner than you think - suppose the initial input vectors are $v_1,\cdots,v_k$ and GS outputs $w_1,\cdots,w_k$. Showing that the span of $Tw_1,\cdots,Tw_k$ is the same as the span of $Tv_1,\cdots,Tv_k$ is basically trivial, and the fact that $Tw_1,\cdots,Tw_k$ is still orthonormal is just a consequence of $T$'s orthogonality.